# Trim function not removing spaces in name

Tags: asp.net, trim, dataview, rowfilter

```
bool Res = false;  

DataView DV = new DataView(DT);
     DV.RowFilter = "Trim(Originator)='"+OrginatorName.Trim()+"'";
     if (DV.Count > 0)
     {
       Res = true;
     }
```

I need to get "Originator" from the database and compare it with the OrginatorName to check duplicate values. I need to remove all the white spaces before checking.

For example, the function must consider "John Van" to be the same as "JohnVan". My above code doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.Trim()` removes whitespace from the beginning and end only, not in the middle. You want to use the `String.Replace()` method

```
DV.RowFilter = "Trim(Originator)='"+OrginatorName.Replace(" ", "")+"'";
```

Comment: +1, you can read about the Trim function here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx

Comment: Then i also need to use Replace function with Originator Can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

this line should be

```
  DV.RowFilter = "Trim(Originator)='"+OrginatorName.Replace(" ","")+"'";
```

Comment: Then i also need to use Replace function with Originator Can i do that?

Comment: You mean replace "Originator" with something else? Yes you can use Replace for that.

Answer (score 2):

User .Replace instead of .Trim()

Comment: Then i also need to use Replace function with Originator Can i do that?